# How can I make the browser window slimmer?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

The default browser window has a limited minimum width. I like to work with a slim browser on the right and a wide editor on the left.

How can I make the browser's window slimmer? How can I resize the browser window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with JavaScript:

```js
//path should be with "http://" unless it is local or something
newwindow=window.open(<path>, 'name', 'height=650, width=320, top=0, left=1200');
```

The code will open a new window that is more resizeable.
The window has lower minimum width, and another plus: has smaller top bar overall.

Open the project with this kind of window from JavaScript in another webpage.

[Here](https://va9iff.github.io/winresizer/) is a GitHub project for just opening this resizable browser window.